# Gelman-Rubin statistic for MCMCglmm model in R

Tags: r, mcmc

I have a multivariate model with this (approximate) form:

```
library(MCMCglmm)

mod.1 <- MCMCglmm(
    cbind(OFT1, MIS1, PC1, PC2) ~ 
    trait-1 +
    trait:sex +
    trait:date,
    random = ~us(trait):squirrel_id + us(trait):year,
    rcov = ~us(trait):units, 
    family = c("gaussian", "gaussian", "gaussian", "gaussian"),
    data= final_MCMC, 
    prior = prior.invgamma, 
    verbose = FALSE,
    pr=TRUE, #this saves the BLUPs 
    nitt=103000, #number of iterations
    thin=100, #interval at which the Markov chain is stored
    burnin=3000)
```

For publication purposes, I've been asked to report the Gelman-Rubin statistic to indicate that the model has converged.

I have been trying to run:

```
gelman.diag(mod.1)
```

But, I get this error:

```
Error in mcmc.list(x) : Arguments must be mcmc objects
```

Any suggestions on the proper approach? I assume that the error means I can't pass my `mod.1` output through `gelman.diag()`, but I am not sure what it is I am supposed to put there instead?  My knowledge is quite limited here, so I'd appreciate any and all help!

*Note that I haven't added the data here, but I suspect the answer is more code syntax and not data related.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gelman.diag` requires a `mcmc.list`.  If we are running models with different set of parameters, extract the 'Sol' and place it in a `list` (Below, it is the same model)

```
library(MCMCglmm)
model1 <- MCMCglmm(PO~1, random=~FSfamily, data=PlodiaPO, verbose=FALSE,
  nitt=1300, burnin=300, thin=1)
model2 <- MCMCglmm(PO~1, random=~FSfamily, data=PlodiaPO, verbose=FALSE,
  nitt=1300, burnin=300, thin=1 )

mclist <- mcmc.list(model1$Sol, model2$Sol)
gelman.diag(mclist)
# gelman.diag(mclist)
#Potential scale reduction factors:
#            Point est. Upper C.I.
#(Intercept)          1          1
```

---

According to the documentation, it seems to be applicable for more than one mcmc chain

> Gelman and Rubin (1992) propose a general approach to monitoring convergence of MCMC output in which m > 1 parallel chains are run with starting values that are overdispersed relative to the posterior distribution.

The input `x` here is

> x - An mcmc.list object with more than one chain, and with starting values that are overdispersed with respect to the posterior distribution.

Comment: If I only am running 1 `MCMCglmm()` model, is it bad practice to just go: `mclist <- mcmc.list(model1$Sol, model1$Sol)`?

Comment: @BlunderingEcologist according to the documentation, it clearly mentions that the input `x` - `An mcmc.list object with more than one chain, and with starting values that are overdispersed with respect to the posterior distribution.`

Comment: @BlunderingEcologist probably, their request may be to run multiplle chains for checking convergence

Comment: I am quite out of my depth here with respect to understanding the documentation. You're follow-up comment might be it (like running a second model with different values of `nitt`, `burnin`, and `thin`?).

Comment: @BlunderingEcologist  the documentation and code examples are kind of limited.  You may need to read the whole description especially their vignettes if available.

Comment: @BlunderingEcologist it may be a better idea to ask a theoretical question in crossvalidated regarding this.  That may help you better

Comment: You need to run multiple chains with different **starting parameter values** in order for the Gelman-Rubin diagnostic make any sense (changing burn-in/number of iterations/etc. is irrelevant) .  MCMCglmm does have a `start` argument, so this should be doable (but you will have to figure out/decide what range of starting values is sensible for your problem).

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks for elaborating on that! I'll have to read more about how to decide on the start in that case.